# Error when trying to query _Job system data view

Tags: marketing-cloud, sqlserver

I'm trying to run a query to a data extension to grab info in the last 30 days from the _Job data view.

I continue to get the error:

> "_Job is not a known data extension or system dat view."

This is the query I'm using. Can anyone see what the problem might be?

```
SELECT
JobID,
EmailID,
AccountID,
EventID,
JobType,
EmailName,
EmailSubject,
EmailSendDefinition,
DeliveredTime
FROM
    _Job
WHERE
    DeliveredTime >= getdate()-30
```

Answer (score 2):

[System Data Views](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) have to be enabled by SFMC Support.  There's no cost.

Comment: Had same issue, when support enabled it, everything was ok again :-)